# Safari opens tabs by itself and launches Mail

Tags: safari, email, tabs

I am using Safari Version 7.1 (9537.85.10.17.1) on OS X Version 10.9.5  Which I got free from Apple when they were offering it.  My Mac is about 5 years old.

When I open Safari it usually opens on the 3 tabs I closed it with (gmail, Facebook, twitter).  Sometimes I leave a random site open to read later.   I like the way it opens with the tabs I was viewing last time.  This works pretty well.

Lately I have noticed that when I open Safari it has 50 or more tabs open and one of them opens my Mail program which I never use (I have my comcast mail sent to a folder of the same name in gmail since I rarely use it).  What is going on here?  Is it a glitch or should I start entertaining paranoia about being cracked?